# firebase_core is throwing exception in its generated file

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

this is the error i am getting when i try to build my app .

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.17.1\android\build.gradle' line: 18

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':firebase_core'.
> Illegal char > at index 31: C:\Users\vikra\fc-ui\android\.uild\firebase_core

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

i have  removed the dependency addded it again.
deleted pubspec.lock file.
changing the version of firebase_core .
I have also tried to delete the firebase files that in the path "C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org".and did flutter  pub get again . but nothing seems to work .

here is my pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  sizer: ^2.0.15
  device_preview: ^1.0.0
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.5
  file_picker: ^4.5.1
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  shared_preferences:
  intl:
  shimmer:
  firebase_messaging:
#  flutter_local_notifications:
  firebase_core: ^1.17.0
  cloud_firestore:
  random_string:
  # sentry_flutter: ^6.5.1
  package_info_plus: ^1.4.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.0
  flutter_dotenv:
  flutter_native_splash:
  dio:
  http_parser:
  audioplayers:
  open_file: ^3.2.1
  isar:


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.2"


  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1



flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  # ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"

flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#ffffff"
  image: assets/icon/icon.png


  uses-material-design: true
```

And this is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

ext {
    var = 'C:\\Users\\vinay\\Desktop\\FC\\keys\\vikrant-keys.jks'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '..\build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you run pub get after adding it in pubspec.yaml?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it was because in the build.gradle `rootProject.buildDir = '..\build'` this is different for MacOs and windows. and i was trying to build it with MacOS format .As soon as i changed it to the windows format .it worked fine . there was no issue with firebase_core.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).